# UK visa for on site interview

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel

I am a techie living in India. I have been invited for an on-site interview for a big tech company in London. I have never been out of India, so this is pretty confusing to me.

So my question is what type of visa is required for such purpose? Should I contact some agent to fill up the documents for me for a fee? What documents will I need from the company and what other documents do I need to submit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a Standard Visitor visa. It is issued for 6 months and is multi-entry, so technically you'll be able to visit UK few times more. The official application portal is here: https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa though the process may appear confusing to some extent. When you arrive at a consulate (or wherever is your nearest point of applying for UK visas — there's a list on that site, they will ask you to pick the least inconvenient point and time), give them the invitation letter from that company, all your docs and anything required on that site.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Multi entry sounds good to me.

Answer (score 6):

The employing company will tell you everything you need to know, and they will pay all fees. If they fail to do that then this is likely to be a scam.

Make sure that the company is on the UK government list of approved visa sponsors otherwise, again, it's a scam.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The company is definitely in the list (I have checked, just to be sure) and it's not a scam. I will ask them to help me out. I guess I am just quick to jump on conclusions that I have to do things on my own. Thanks again